# generate 18 digit unique number

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function in my NodeJS application which generates unique 18 digit numbers. What I'm expecting is to get unique 18 digit numbers like below:

```
73306495056092753667
```

I thought of using the below logic, by combining Date.now() with Math.random():

```
Date.now()+""+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000)
```

But in cases where my function is called exactly at the same millisecond, and if in the same cases, Math.random() returns the same value, the above logic wont return unique ID's.

In NodeJS/Javascript, is there any module like UUID which generates globally unique numerical values? Or can anyone help me create an algorithm that will generate unique ID's?

Comment: You might want to look into how Mongo generates its ids (as an example).

Comment: @John I checked that, Mongo generates alpha-numerical ids. What I want it strictly numerical

Comment: I said _how_ it generates its ids. I didn't say you should generate the same ids as Mongo. And it's alphanumeric because Mongo represents the number as hexadecimal. Anyway, it generates a 4-byte timestamp, a 5-byte random value, and a 3-byte incrementing counter. That way even if you generate 2 numbers at the exact same moment, you get two different ids.

Comment: Please note that hexadecimal is just a representation of binary data, and as such you could also interpret that same binary data as numbers, for example. The Mongo ID `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011` could also be written as `24912482966938930280208240657` in decimal.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution using [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) (`npm install -S nanoid`):

```
const { customAlphabet } = require('nanoid')
const nanoid = customAlphabet('1234567890', 18)
console.log(nanoid()) // sample outputs => 455712511712968405, 753952709650782495
```

Comment: the result of customAlphabet is always unique?  `customAlphabet('1234567890', 18)`

Comment: The documentation of this functions says it is.
`Generate secure unique ID with custom alphabet.`

Answer (score 0):

Try appending a *random number between 10000 and 99999* to [`new Date().valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

```js
const numbers = [...Array(90000).keys()].map(n => n + 10000);
let filteredNumbers = numbers;
let timeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
let rand = 0;
const generateRandomNumber = _ => {
  const currentTimeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
  if (timeStamp === currentTimeStamp && rand !== 0) {
    filteredNumbers = filteredNumbers.filter(n => n !== value)
  } else {
    timeStamp = currentTimeStamp;
    filteredNumbers = numbers;
  }
  rand = filteredNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredNumbers.length)];
  return parseInt(new Date().valueOf() + "" + rand, 10);
};

document.querySelector('#generate')
  .addEventListener('click', _ => {
    const uuid = generateRandomNumber();
    console.log(uuid);
  });
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate UUID</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is almost same as what I have did so far, if you look at my question. The problem with this approach is that there can be cases(even though its rare), where user clicks on this 'Generate UUID' button at the same milliseconds(which is what new Date().valueOf() returns), and the same random number being generated in those cases

Comment: updated to bypass the issue. wont work if it happens more than 90000 times in a millisecond.

Comment: I dont think this is efficient solution though (interms of memory for instance).. If you could remove the necessity for the numbers array and the loop, it would be awesome (1st line)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly Same 18 Digits as my laravel Projects

Well In this case I Created that with `10 digiths Seconds + randomiser like 3+3+2 digits`
Maybe It Kind of what @Naveen did